# How to handle large images in android

Tags: android, image

i'm writing a simple application. i need to handle around 100 images having size dimension 1000*740. images are fixed no need to change. user will see this images like gallery view.

Problem
1.Large number of Images increases .apk filesize .It crosses memory limit(Given by **Android market**).
2.I placed these images in **Drawable** folder.Is there any other way to keep this images?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

YOu can host them on a separate site, but you do not have to download them every time. You can download them to an external directory (sd card) and just check if you've got everything you want when starting the app: If you do, you obviously don't have to re-download the shots again.

Is there a reason your images are of that size? If you compress them a bit you should be able to fit a photo in less then half an MB, and I think that the limit is 50mb on the market: You might be able to just squeeze it in.

Answer (score 1):

Upload all the images to a link. Do parsing by using that link.

Comment: Like uploading pics in gmail or picasa you upload your pics and make a link.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty tough dilemma. Perhaps the user can download the images instead. You could use flickr to host the images.

Comment: then when app runs every time it need to connect the internet no?

Comment: That's correct, unfortunately your options are extremely limited.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest hosting them somewhere and download as "citizen conn" suggested.

Another possibility would be to separate in different sets and have different apk with those (maybe some of them would only have a content provider with some of those pictures). But that's kind of ugly...

Other than that, I don't think there is any way to get around the limit from Android market...